# Z-Algorithm for pattern matching in strings

Tags: python, algorithm, strings, python-2.x, search

I was trying to refactor the following Python code (keeping the same time-complexity) which is an implementation of Z-Algorithm for pattern matching in strings.

> ```
> def compute_z(string):
>    n = len(string)
>    z = [n]
>
>    L = R = 0
>    for i in xrange(1,n):
>         if (i > R):
>             L = R = i
>             while (R < n and string[R-L] == string[R]): R+=1
>             z.append(R-L)
>             R -= 1
>         else:
>             k = i-L
>             if (z[k] < R-i): z.append(z[k])
>             else:
>                 L = i
>                 while (R < n and string[R-L] == string[R]): R += 1
>                 z.append(R-L)
>                 R -= 1
> ```

I was thinking of using `lambda` but it returns expressions and I need to store the values in `z` array. So I could not think of a way of using `lambda`.

The max I could refactor was this:

```
def g(L,R,string):
    L=i
    while (R < len(string) and string[R-L] == string[R]): R += 1
    return L,R

def compute_z(string):
   n = len(string)
   z = [n]

   L = R = 0
   for i in xrange(1,n):
        if (i > R):
            R = i
            L,R = g(L,R,string)
            z.append(R-L+1)
        else:
            k = i-L
            if (z[k] < R-i): z.append(z[k])  
            else:
                L,R = g(L,R,string)
                z.append(R-L+1)
```

Could it be any further refactored?

NOTE: Z-Algorithm is defined as `z(i)` = number of characters in the prefix of `s(i)` that matches the prefix of `S`.

For example, a string `S = 'abaab'`. The substrings of `S` are

```
s(0) = 'abaab' = S
s(1) = 'baab'
s(2) = 'aab'
s(3) = 'ab'
s(4) = 'b'
```

The `z` values are respectively

```
z(0) = 5 = length(S)
z(1) = 0
z(2) = 1
z(3) = 2
z(4) = 0
```

For more details, see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFK0WYeVEag).

Comment: FYI, if `g` is only going to be used by `Func`, you can declare it *inside of* `Func`. Also, those are some truly awful function names.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Bugs

- In your original `compute_z()`, you fail to `return z`.
- In your refactored solution, `g()` has an undefined variable `i`.
- The correct z-values for `'abaab'` are `[5, 0, 1, 2, 0]`, not `[6, 0, 1, 2, 0]`.

Questions containing non-working code would normally be closed on Code Review, but since @jonrsharpe has already posted an answer, I'll let it slide.  Since the refactored solution is unreviewable in its current state, I'll examine only the original `compute_z()`.

### Reverse engineering

I was, admittedly, unfamiliar with the Z Algorithm.  I stared at `compute_z()`, befuddled by the cryptically named variables `i`, `k`, `L`, `R`, and by the purpose of the each `if`- and `else`-branch.  Frankly, my experience was closer to reverse-engineering than reading the code.

I came to the realization that I could strip the code down to the following and still get the same result.

```
def naive_z(string):
    n = len(string)
    z = [n]

    for i in xrange(1, n):
        L = R = i
        while (R < n and string[R - L] == string[R]): R += 1
        z.append(R - L)
    return z
```

I therefore surmised that the rest of the code served as some kind of optimization, in particular, `if (z[k] < R-i): z.append(z[k])`.

I also wondered about the `R -= 1` statements.  I figured out that there was a loop invariant: at the bottom of the for-loop, `string[L : R + 1]` was the longest common prefix.

At that point, I decided to give up and start educating myself about the Z Algorithm. ☺

In the end, I decided that the algorithm is complex enough that it wouldn't be reasonable to assume that the underlying principles would be self-evident just by reading the code.  So, I learned something new today.

### Observations

Your implementation appears to be a direct translation of the C code at http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3107.

Superficial criticisms first: you have a few PEP 8 violations.  Notably, the first level of indentation is only 3 spaces, which in Python is a big deal.  The variables `L` and `R` violate capitalization conventions, though arguably `L` is more readable than `l`.  You also have a few C-isms, such as parentheses around the `if`-conditions.

Rather than appending one element at a time to `z`, you should pre-allocate an `n`-element list at the beginning.  Otherwise, the array might need to be reallocated as it grows.

You miss out on some optimizations due to a botched inequality.  `if (z[k] < R-i)` should be `if z[i] <= R - i`.

The `R -= 1` statements are awkward, and should be eliminated.  In languages where strings are indexed starting from 0, it would be more idiomatic to use inclusive-exclusive bounds.  In other words, `R` should point *just past the end* of the match, such that `string[L:R]` is the longest matching prefix.

The concern that prompted you to write this question is probably the repetition of the `while` loops.  It is indeed possible to restructure the code such that the loop only appears once.

```
def compute_z(string):
    n = len(string)                                                                                                                 
    z = [0] * n                                                                                                                     

    zbox_l, zbox_r, z[0] = 0, 0, n                                                                                                  
    for i in xrange(1, n):          
        if i < zbox_r:              # i is within a zbox                                                                            
            k = i - zbox_l
            if z[k] < zbox_r - i:   
                z[i] = z[k]         # Full optimization                                                                             
                continue            
            zbox_l = i              # Partial optimization                                                                          
        else:
            zbox_l = zbox_r = i     # Match from scratch
        while zbox_r < n and string[zbox_r - zbox_l] == string[zbox_r]:                                                             
            zbox_r += 1 
        z[i] = zbox_r - zbox_l                                                                                                      
    return z
```