# String self-similarity

Tags: optimization, performance, c, strings, programming-challenge

It's a string problem I have been making on [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/string-similarity). It is executing fine on all test cases except the last two. These last two test case are declaring it "Terminated due to time out".

C programs are allowed 2 seconds on this site and somehow my program is taking a fraction beyond 2 seconds. How am I supposed to reduce that time taken?

> For two strings A and B, we define the similarity
>   of the strings to be the length of the longest prefix common to both
>   strings. For example, the similarity of strings "abc" and "abd" is 2,
>   while the similarity of strings "aaa" and "aaab" is 3.
>
> Calculate the sum of similarities of a string S with each of its suffixes.

```
   #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void stringMatch(char strMain[]) {
        int similarity = 0,i,j;
        for(i =0;i<strlen(strMain);i++){
            for(j =0;j+i<strlen(strMain);j++){
                if(strMain[j] == strMain[j+i]){
                    similarity++;
                }else{
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        printf("%d\n",similarity);
}

int main(){
        int T,i;
        scanf("%d",&T);
        char str[1000000];
        for(i =0;i<T;i++){
            scanf("%s",str);
            stringMatch(str);
        }
}
```

Comment: The errors have gone away, so this has been reopened.  Please remember to include *all* code so that others can compile and run it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You re-calculate string length every iteration of every loop:

```
    for(i =0;i<strlen(strMain);i++){
        for(j =0;j+i<strlen(strMain);j++){
```

It does not look like the string changes length. So calculate it once.

```
    size_t  size = strlen(strMain);
    for(i =0; i < size; i++){
        for(j =0; j+i < size; j++){
```

Or don't even calculate it at all. The string is terminated when you reach the '\0' character so just look for that

```
    for(i =0; strMain[i]; i++){
        for(j =0; strMain[j+i]; j++){
```

The other thing I noticed is that you are checking the string against itself. Which is not similar to the description you give above (where you are comparing two different strings).

Comment: still it dint work. taking 3 seconds. :(

Comment: Look at my newly posted solution.... it worked for me... i don't know why i got down votes though....

Answer (score 3):

Your solution takes O(*L*<sup>3</sup>) time, where *L* is the length of the string. There are two levels of for-loops, each of which is O(*L*). However, you call `strlen()` repeatedly, and `strlen()` is O(*L*).  You shouldn't need to call `strlen()` at all of you just look for the `\0` terminator as you iterate.  That would bring it down to O(*L*<sup>2</sup>).

However, what you really need is a smarter algorithm.  As it happens, I reviewed just such an algorithm a few days ago, called the [Z Algorithm](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/53852/9357), which returns an array of the lengths of self-similar prefixes.  That should work in O(*L*) time and O(*L*) space.

Answer (score -3):

The problem with the slow running time is due to the presence of two loops in your code. In this particular case, only one suffices. The following code should be fast enough to pass your benchmarking test.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
/* Head ends here */

int commonPrefix(char* a, char* b) {
    char *x, *y;

    for (x = a, y = b; *x && *y; x++, y++) {
        if (*x != *y)
            break;
    }
    return x-a;
}

int stringSimilarity(char *a) {
    int len = strlen(a);
    char *suffix;
    int i, sum = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
        suffix = a + len-i;
        sum += commonPrefix(a, suffix);
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    int res, t, i;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    char a[100001];
    for (i=0;i<t;i++) {
        scanf("%s",a);
        res=stringSimilarity(a);
        printf("%d\n",res);  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't just dump your code here for the OP to use.  Explain what you changed specifically and why the OP should change it to the way you have it.

Comment: In my previous code, I only wrote the commonPrefix function. I missed his question of addressing the self similarity, the function for which is now added in the new code. I've checked that the pasted code passes the Hackerrank test.

Comment: The nested for-loops still exist. You've just hidden one of them inside a helper function, that's all.

Comment: @Debasis Nopes, this solution isn't improving time. for the last 2 test cases it is taking 3 seconds. Same time my solution was taking.