# Finding string roots

Tags: python, algorithm, strings, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

This is the following Python code that I have coded for an [algorithmic problem online](http://www.spoj.com/problems/FINDSR/).  For each line of input, the goal is to find the greatest number of repeating blocks into which the string can be split.  For example, if the input is `abcabcabcabc`, then the output should be 4, because the string is equal to 4 repetitions of `abc`.

The online compiler says "Time Limit Exceeded". Where in the following code can I optimize to make it much more efficient in terms of time?

```
inputString = raw_input()
while (inputString !='*'):
   scanned_string = ""
   matched_characters = ""
   frequency = 0
   if (len(inputString) == 1):
     print frequency
   for current_symbol in inputString:
     if not scanned_string:
        scanned_string = scanned_string + current_symbol
     if scanned_string:
        matched_characters = matched_characters + current_symbol
        if (scanned_string.startswith(matched_characters)):
            if (len(scanned_string) == len(matched_characters)):
                frequency = frequency + 1
                matched_characters = ""
        else:
            scanned_string = scanned_string+matched_characters
            matched_characters = ""
            frequency = 1
   print frequency
   inputString = raw_input()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that:

- The length of a root must be a divisor of the length of the input string: you could skip other lengths. For example for the input string "abcabcabc" (length = 9), "ab" (length = 2) or "abcd" (length = 4) cannot be a root, so no need to check those
- The length of a root must be less than equal to half the length of the input string, otherwise it's the input string itself (frequency = 1)

Taking the above into consideration, this implementation should be faster:

```
def sroot(text):
    text_len = len(text)
    for segment_len in range(1, text_len // 2 + 1):
        if text_len % segment_len != 0:
            continue
        frequency = text_len // segment_len
        if text[:segment_len] * frequency == text:
            return frequency
    return 1
```

This can be further improved too.
For example, instead of iterating until `text_len // 2`,
it would be enough to iterate until `math.sqrt(text_len)`,
and when finding a divisor, also try its factor pair as a possible segment.
For example for `text_len = 100`,
when finding `segment_len = 5`,
also try `segment_len = 100 / 5 = 20`.
Iterating until 10 will be a lot faster than iterating until 50 as in the example implementation above.

There are several coding style issues in your code:

- It's good to put the main logic inside a function. It makes it easier to test. For example you can add assertions like this to test your solution:

  ```
  assert sroot('abcabcabcabc') == 4
  assert sroot('abcdefgh012') == 1
  assert sroot('aaaaaaaaaa') == 10
  assert sroot('abcdefgh012abcdefgh012') == 2
  assert sroot('abcdefgh012abcdefgh012x') == 1
  ```
- Lots of unnecessary parentheses, for example in:

  > ```
  > while (inputString !='*'):
  > if (len(inputString) == 1):
  > ```
- This can be simplified:

  > ```
  >  if not scanned_string:
  >     scanned_string = scanned_string + current_symbol
  > ```

  to this:

  ```
   if not scanned_string:
      scanned_string = current_symbol
  ```
- This can be simplified:

  > ```
  > matched_characters = matched_characters + current_symbol
  > ```

  to this:

  ```
  matched_characters += current_symbol
  ```

Comment: can you be more explicit about your first statement of your answer?

Comment: Which statement do you mean?

Comment: The length of a root must be a divisor of the length of the input string: you could skip other lengths. For example for the input string "abcabcabc" (length = 9), "ab" (length = 2) or "abcd" (length = 4) cannot be a root, so no need to check those
    The length of a root must be less than equal to half the length of the input string, otherwise it's the input string itself (frequency = 1)

Comment: For an input string of length 9 for example, the possible root lengths are 1, 3 and 9 only. There's no need to example if a segment of length 2 will add up to the input string, because no multiple of 2 will add up to 9. Considering this, the algorithm can skip checking many unnecessary combinations, and thus become faster.

Comment: Good answer. IMHO `range(1, text_len // 2+1):` would have been more readable than adding `1` in the loop.

Comment: Thanks @Veedrac, I kinda agree with you.... So I changed it now, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @janos Does this operation if text[:segment_len] * frequency == text:               take constant time( O(1))?

Comment: @DiljitPR string comparison is \$O(n)\$, where \$n\$ is the length of the string

Comment: @janos the algorithm takes quadratic amount of time right?

Comment: @DiljitPR the algorithm is \$O(nm)\$ where \$n\$ is the length of the string, and \$m\$ is the number of divisors of \$n\$, which is much smaller than \$n\$. So maybe it's \$O(n\log n)\$ but I'm not sure. You can try to pick the brains of 200_success or Rolfl in the 2nd monitor chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor

Answer (score 3):

#### Mysterious special case

For any `inputString` with length 1, you print two lines of output: `0` followed by `1`.  The incorrect `0` comes from the special case

```
if (len(inputString) == 1):
  print frequency
```

which as far as I can tell should not be there at all.

#### Style

Consistent indentation is important, especially in Python, where whitespace matters.  Use 4 spaces, as recommended in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

`inputString` should be `input_string` to be consistent with the naming style and Python guidelines.

It is customary to omit parentheses after `while`, `if`, and `for`.

You should split your code according to responsibilities.  I recommend the following outline:

```
def string_root(s):
    …
    return n

def lines(terminator='*'):
    s = raw_input()
    while s != terminator:
        yield s
        s = raw_input()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for line in lines():
        print string_root(line)
```

Advantages include:

- The main loop read like English.  It makes it obvious that each line is treated as an independent problem, unaffected by all other lines.
- The two calls to `raw_input()` are close to each other.  (Unfortunately, there's no do-while loop in Python.)
- The `string_root()` function is independently testable.

#### Algorithm

You've implemented a brute-force solution.  The complexity is \$O(L^2)\$, there \$L\$ is the length of `inputString`.  (You can tell because `for current_symbol in inputString` is \$O(L)\$, and `scanned_string.startswith(matched_characters)` is also \$O(L)\$, and there are no `break` statements anywhere to serve as shortcuts.)

To bring it down to \$O(L)\$, you would need a smarter string-matching algorithm.  The [Z Algorithm](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/53969/9357) is useful here: it detects string self-similarities in \$O(L)\$ time.

> ```
> >>> compute_z('abc' * 4)
> [12, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0]
> ```

The result above means that `'abcabcabcabc'` has

- 12 leading characters in common with itself
- no leading characters in common with itself after dropping the initial `'a'`
- no leading characters in common with itself after dropping the initial `'ab'`
- 9 leading characters in common with itself after dropping the initial `'abc'`
- …

This implementation works in \$O(L)\$ time.

```
def string_root(s):
    z = compute_z(s)
    z_iter = enumerate(z)
    _, s_len = next(z_iter)
    for block_len, remain_len in z_iter:
        if remain_len == s_len - block_len and remain_len % block_len == 0:
            return s_len // block_len
    return 1
```

#### Documentation and testing

A [doctest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html) would be useful here.

```
def string_root(s):
    """Returns the maximum number of repeating blocks into which string s
    can be split.

    >>> string_root('abcabcabcabc')
    4
    >>> string_root('abcdefgh012')
    1       
    >>> string_root('aaaaaaaaaa')
    10
    >>> string_root('abcabcabcabcd')
    1
    >>> string_root('abcabcdabcabcd')
    2
    >>> string_root('abcabcabcabx')
    1
    """
    z = compute_z(s)
    …
```

Then you can test the code using

```
import findsr
import doctest
doctest.testmod(findsr)
```